When querying the database with sqlalchemy, it gives InvalidRequestError
I faced a problem, when I create models everything goes smoothly, but when I try to make any query I get this error
class Phone(Base):
__tablename__ = 'phone'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    number: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(PhoneNumberType(region="BY"), unique=True)
    contact_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('contacts.id'))
    
    contacts: Mapped[list['Contacts']] = relationship('Contacts', back_populates='phone')

class Socials(Base):
__tablename__ = 'socials'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True)
    contact_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('contacts.id'))
    
    contacts: Mapped[list['Contacts']] = relationship('Contacts', back_populates='socials')

class Contacts(Base):
__tablename__ = 'contacts'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    address: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    
    social: Mapped[list['Socials']] = relationship('Socials', back_populates='contacts')
    phone: Mapped[list['Phone']] =relationship('Phone', back_populates='contacts')

When executing any query, an error occurs: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper 'Mapper[Contacts(contacts)]' has no property 'socials'.  If this property was indicated from other mappers or configure events, ensure registry.configure() has been called.
